# Trying to make a discord js kick command, but it kicks based on user id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord kick command that kicks a specific person on my server. Yes, it isn't very practical but this is exactly what my bot needs.
This is my code:

```js
if (command == "kickderek") {
    let member = message.guild.member("<@userid>");
    member.kick();
    kickd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    if (kickd == 1) {
        member.kick();
        message.channel.send("God has accepted your wish and derek has been kicked");
        return;
    } else {
        message.channel.send("Try again, you failed kicking derek");
        return;
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it I get the error:

```
/home/admin/discbot/disc.js:357
    member.kick();
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kick' of null
at Client.<anonymous> (/home/admin/discbot/disc.js:357:16)
at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/admin/discbot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
```

Can someone help me solve this problem, I have been working on it for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'kick' of null` means that the member part of `member.kick` if not defined, meaning that when you defined member, `let member = message.guild.member('<@userid>');` is returning null.
Just pass the userid without the bracket notation: `let member = message.guild.member(USERID);`

P.S. If you're trying to only kick after the RNG roll, you have a typo in your code: You call kick before the rng rolls

```js
member.kick();
kickd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
if(kickd == 1){
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The member.kick was before the RNG just for testing but thank you